# Select a number of rows from a set in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of users in locations within my company.  Vastly reduced from the 130,000 or so in reality, the data looks like the example at the end.

What I need to do is to select a number of users from each location. In this instance it's two, so I would pick Tom and Dick from "A House", Bob and Charlie from "The Place" and so on.

This is a trivial excercise if I import the data into SQL, which is how I solved the problem, but I would like to know how to do it in Excel so that the end user who presented it to me could do it themselves in Excel in future.

```
Building:   User
A House:    Tom
A House:    Dick
A House:    Harry
A House:    Alice
The Place:  Bob
The Place:  Charlie
The Place:  Fred
The Place:  Ginger
My Drive:   Simon
My Drive:   Peter
Long St:    Matthew
Long St:    Mark
Long St:    Luke
Big House:  Gloria
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is by using Excel's filter function. Depending on the version of excel used, getting it to filter will work differently. Given that you haven't mentioned which version you are using, I'll assume you use Excel 2013.

1. Click `insert` -> `Table`
2. Click on the icon on the right of where you type your range.
3. Make a selection that spans all your cells (or select the columns if the data is too much)
4. On the popup window, hit OK.
5. Check "This table has headers" if you have the Building : User present as in your example.
6. Now, there are small boxes with arrows in the header cells. Click the one in the Building one to only view by a specific type. All rows except those are hidden.

See also: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-Excel-table-in-a-worksheet-e81aa349-b006-4f8a-9806-5af9df0ac664?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: That would work, but in the real data I have 100,000 rows, and something like 90+ categories categories. So I would need to filter for each category and pick three and repeat for each category.
I was hoping there was a formula I could use to put a "Y" in a third column where a rows was chosen, and then filter on that column to select the 270 rows I needed in one go.

Comment: Same method applies. You make a column, enter all the Y's you need, then create that data table, and filter on your new column, everywhere there is a Y and presto, only those rows are visible.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your data are grouped by Building/Location. 
And I’ll assume that you are showing us Columns `A` and `B`, and that you have headers on Row `1`.

Enter some text in cell `C1`
(or the head cell of a column that’s available to use as a helper column). 
In the next cell down (`C2`), enter

```
=IF(A1<>A2, 1, C1+1)
```

and drag/fill that down all 100,000<sup>+</sup> rows.  This will count rows (people) per location:

[image]

Now it’s a simple matter to filter Column `C` and display only rows that contain 1 or 2. 
Or you could add Column `D`:

```
=(C2<=2)
```

which will evaluate to `TRUE` in the rows that you want to select.